# How to write a long integral in Latex

Tags: pdftex

Please help me in this problem. I want to write the long integrals as in the picture. Here is my code, but it doesn't work in Texmaker. Please help!
Many thanks!

```
\begin{align}%\label{2.37}
\begin{split}
&\left\|r_{xx}\right\|^2_{L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}=\sup_{t}{\int_0^1{\left(\int_0^t{\left(\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1{\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)}dx}cat_{xx}(u+g)+\right. \right.\\
&\left. \left.+2\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1{\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)}dx}cat_{x}(u_x+g_x)+\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1{\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)}dx}cat(x)(u_{xx}+g_{xx})\right)d\tau\right)^2}}dx}\leq
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post full compilable codes, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: 'Doesn't work' isn't very helpful, but what you need to do is (i) delete unnecessary braces, (ii) check that the remaining braces match up, and (iii) correct the braces that don't match.

Answer (score 2):

I propose this layout in three lines, based on the `flalign` environment. I took the liberty to interpret `cat` as the name of some function, which therefore has to be typed in roman, so I declared it as a math operator through the command `\cat`. I also defined a `\norm`command, with a starred version which automatically adjusts to its content, and a`\dd` command for the differential symbol in integrals, with a correct spacing, typed in upshape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cat}{cat}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} %% differential symbol for integrals

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}%\label{2.37}
  & \mathrlap{\norm{r_{xx}}^2_{L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega ))}=} & & & &\notag \\
  & &\sup_{t}\int_0^1\Biggl(\int_0^t\Biggl(\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1 \bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon }(\bar{u}+g)\dd x} \cat_{xx}(u+g)+2\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1{\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon }(\bar{u}+g)}\dd x}\cat_{x}(u_x+g_x)& \\[-1ex]
  & &{}+ \frac{D_2}{\int_0^1\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon }(\bar{u}+g)dx} \cat(x)(u_{xx}+g_{xx})\Biggr)\!\dd\tau&\Biggr)^{\!\!2\!}\dd x\leq \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) for idea of three lines, but i can't compile your code with `\pdflatex` nor `xelatex` ... errors: unknown codeharacters for integrals, greek letters ... please explain in answer how to compile your mwe

Comment: Oops! Sorry, it's my fault: my editor displays a number of mathematical characters instead of the commands (somewhat like pretty-printing), to make the code easier to read, but naturally saves the commands, and I forgot to check the details. I've fixed  it  and it should be compilable by now.

Comment: The definition `\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` yields the same result and is much simpler.

Comment: @egreg: I don't remember where I borrowed this code  from (on this site anyway), but yours is definitely more elegant. Trying is adopting! Thanks for all your tips…

Comment: after second editing your code again isn't compilable ... the same problem as i notice in the my first comment :(

Comment: Oh! yes. I've fixed it. Thank you for warning me!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

in three lines using `\MoveEqLeft` and `multlined` environment from `amsmath` and `mathtools` package (the second also load the first) and stolen math operator and idea for defining differentiating operator `d` from [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cat}{cat}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand*{\ud}{\mathrm{\,d}}     % differential symbol for integrals

\begin{document}

\begin{align}%\label{2.37}
    \MoveEqLeft
\norm{r_{xx}}^2_{L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))} = &     \notag    \\
  & \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\linewidth]
  \sup_{t}\int_0^1\left\lgroup\int_0^t 
    \left\lgroup\frac{D_2}{\int_0^t \bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)\ud x} \cat_{xx}(u+g)+2\frac{D_2}{\int_0^1{\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)}\ud x} \cat_{x}(u_x+g_x)\right.\right.                             \\                
    \left.\left.+ \frac{D_2}{\int_0^1\bar{r}\,H_{\epsilon}(\bar{u}+g)\ud x} \cat_x(u_{xx}+g_{xx})\right\rgroup\ud\tau \right\rgroup^{2}\ud x\leq
    \end{multlined}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your support! I have corrected the code by deleting the unnecessary brace {} after int_0^T.